# Routing Engine / data for hiking trails (Austria)

Tags: openstreetmap, routing, navigation, open-source-routing-machine

I currently use OSRM for the routing in my apps. This works well for car/truck routing. However, I have an upcoming project that requires routing on hiking trails as well. Are there any available solutions? If not, would it be feasible to use osrm and add the trails manually to osm? any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OSRM for this purpose but you will require a hiking profile. The [OSRM demo instance](http://map.project-osrm.org/) has just a car profile and won't do foot routing. However that's a limitation of this particular OSRM instance and *not* of the underlying OSM data.

Alternatively just use a different online router. There are lots of different [OSM-based routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) available, many of the support foot routing.

You can also search for official hiking trails in OSM. [waymarkedtrails.org](http://hiking.waymarkedtrails.org/#?map=12!47.2517!11.4035) is a great OSM-based source for all kinds of trails (hiking, cycling, mtb, riding, ...) and offers GPX downloads.

Comment: Note that OSRM doesn't support route relations out of the box, which limits its usefulness for some hiking and cycling uses. There are a couple of possible approaches to solve this.